# StripeToken displaying?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Hello I am trying to setup stripe payment for an e_commerc django application, and I have a problem whit displaying stripeToken, when I try to pay whit the stripe test credit card.
This is my **views.py**, where am I defining mine stripe payment:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import stripe


# Create your views here.
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
    user = request.user
    context = {}
    tempalte = 'checkout.html'
    return render(request, tempalte, context)
```

When I use test credit card it will display only this 
`<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'NP0q3qvVZs2C0dB2yEiSzmMuNMBS9jvD']}>`, whitout stripeToken.
Can you tell me what am I mistaking here?
Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you may not have Stripe set up properly...

Comment: I will try configure it again, tnx for the hint

Comment: I have done like you recommended, but I have the same whit out stripeToken display, this are mine [checkout.html](http://ur1.ca/jrqo1), where script configuration for stripe is, and mine [base.html](http://ur1.ca/jrqok), where I am trying to pass jquery for stripeToken.

Comment: I'm assuming you replaced `YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` with your actual publishable key?

Comment: Yes I replaced whit mine key,  i was thinking about me not properly loading jQuery in base.html, or not?

Comment: Fix it, it was about me not loading java script properly, tnx for the help.